# soup.find() function is not working, how do I find the ID value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I have the following HTML that was found with `BeautifulSoup`, can someone explain why  `print(soup.find(id="style"))` or `print(soup.find(id="id"))` does not work? I am trying to find the id number specifically in the line

`<td style="text-align:center"><a href="?id=6359075900">6359075900</a></td>`

```
 </span>
<br/><br/>
<table>
<tr>
<th class="outer">Criteria</th>
<td class="outer">Type: Identity    Match: ILIKE    Search: 'example.org'</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
<tr>
<th class="outer">Certificates</th>
<td class="outer">
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<a href="?q=example.org&amp;dir=v&amp;sort=0&amp;group=none">crt.sh ID</a>
</th>
<th style="white-space:nowrap">
       <a href="?q=example.org&amp;dir=v&amp;sort=1&amp;group=none">Logged At</a> 
 ⇧    </th>
<th style="white-space:nowrap"><a href="?q=example.org&amp;dir=v&amp;sort=2&amp;group=none">Not Before</a>
</th>
<th style="white-space:nowrap"><a href="?q=example.org&amp;dir=v&amp;sort=4&amp;group=none">Not After</a>
</th>
<th>Common Name</th>
<th>Matching Identities</th>
<th>
<a href="?q=example.org&amp;dir=v&amp;sort=3&amp;group=none">Issuer Name</a>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><a href="?id=6359075900">6359075900</a></td>
<td style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap">2022-03-17</td>
<td style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap">2022-03-14</td>
<td style="text-align:center;white-space:nowrap">2023-03-14</td>
<td>www.example.org</td>
<td>example.org<br/>www.example.org</td>
<td><a href="?caid=185756" style="white-space:normal">C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (*it will find the displayed number, not the value of the id parameter in the link, but I assume it is the same*):

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = open("index.html")      # this is your HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("\?id"))
print(res[0].contents[0])   # 6359075900
```

This works with your example. If you have more than one links with data to extract, you will need to change the regex in the `compile` parameter and iterate through the results instead of using hardcoded indexes as the `[0]` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue, there is no tag with attribute called id in your soup, so you wont `find()` anything.

Try to select your elements more specific e.g. with `css selectors` -> all `href` that contains parameter `?id` :

```
soup.select('a[href*="?id"]')
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><a href="?id=6359075900">6359075900</a></td>
<td><a href="?caid=185756" style="white-space:normal">C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><a href="?id=6359075900">6359075901</a></td>
<td><a href="?caid=185756" style="white-space:normal">C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center"><a href="?id=6359075900">6359075902</a></td>
<td><a href="?caid=185756" style="white-space:normal">C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1</a></td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.select('a[href*="?id"]'):
    print(a.text)
```

###### Output

```
6359075900
6359075901
6359075902
```